# Migrate from Windows 2003 DNS server to Windows 2008 DNS Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, dns-server

I have windows 2003 server that I used its DNs server , I have about 3000 records on it.Now I have to move to a windows 2008 Web server.
How Can I move DNS records ?
I find some doc about old version of windows dns http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280061 but not for windows 2008.

best regards
Mehdi Alidoost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create the new DNS as a secondary for the old one, let the info replicate from the master to the secondary then mark the new DNS as a master?

Simple, works regardless of what platform you're moving from or to... much better than any clever "hacks" like that knowledgebase article suggests, imho.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I check the DNS console, it seems that I have to do this manually for every DNS Zone in forward lookup zones.
and there are many zones , is there any more simple way?

Comment: You might be able to script this to take the burden of repetition out of it, but conceptually there isn't another way that I would trust.

Answer (score 0):

- Export the `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\Zones]` registry key
- stop the DNS service in your new server
- merge the exported registry into your new server: it works on both windows 2003 and 2008
- make your new server the master DNS